# How to unset a specific bit in an integer

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

Say, I have a integer like `10101`, I would like to unset the third bit to get `10001`; if I have `10001`, I will still get `10001`;  how can I achieve it?

```
unset(int i, int j)
int i= 10101 or 10000
int j = 00100
```

Comment: Can you make up your mind about the language?

Comment: Please tell us which programming language you are *actually* using.  (The "code" in your question is  not valid in any of the ones you tagged the question with.)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Assuming that you are indexing bits from the right, this should work to unset a particular bit in `value`:

```
int mask = 1 << bitIndex;
value &= ~mask;
```

You can set the bit using similar code:

```
value |= mask;
```

where `mask` is as before. (This assumes that bit indexing starts at 0.)

Answer (score 14):

To clear or unset a bit

Use the bitwise AND operator (&) to clear a bit.

```
 number &= ~(1 << x);
```

That will clear bit x. You must invert the bit string with the bitwise NOT operator (~), then AND it.

NOTE : here x is the position of bit starting from 0 to LSB.

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle the nth bit

result = number ^ (1 << bitIndex)

Comment: Toggling isn't clearing. OP wants the bit to stay 0 if it is already 0.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with litterals, then you can just work with the hex numbers. Converting your bit patterns to hex numbers:

```
10101 => 0x15
00100 => 0x04
```

So the following C code would set `b` to the result you want.

```
int a = 0x15;
int b = a & ~( 0x04 );
```

If you wanted something generic you could have a C function (with all range checking removed) like

```
int clearBit( int value, int bit )
{
    // Assume we count bits starting at 1
    return value & ~( 1 << (bit -1) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ use **[bit wise AND operator](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/bitande.htm)** to form an AND mask:

```
10101 & 10001
```

Comment: This isn't helpful for unsetting an arbitrary bit, since you'd have to create the mask ahead of time.

Comment: @QuinnTaylor: OP **knows** the bit he wants to unset and specifically says so in the Q, Given that I am afraid the comment and downvote is just pedantic noise.

Comment: The problem with this "solution" is that OP would already have had to form the mask `10001`, when that's precisely what OP is trying to compute. (I read OP's question as asking about the general case, when one doesn't know the actual value of `i` and yet wants to zero out a particular bit.)

Answer (score 0):

[Bitwise functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

In Java:

```
int num = 0b10101;
int mask = 1 << bitPosition;

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(num));
num &= ~mask;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(num));
```

Comment: Incorrect. Your code only works for `N=3`. The `N`th bit is given by `(1 << N)`, for `N = 0..`. Nothing to do with `integerLength`.

Comment: @EJP Ahh, it was late when I was typing this, fixed.