# How could I turn off the third least significant bit of an integer variable in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to unset a specific bit in an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557105/how-to-unset-a-specific-bit-in-an-integer)

Imagine that I have a variable like this:

```
int n = 465;
```

How could I turn off the third least significant bit?

Comment: `n &= ~4;` would do it. But it's already turned off in 465.

Answer (score 2):

The third least significant bit is (1<<2). To turn off, AND with all bits 1 except for that.

n &= ~(1 << 2)

(EDIT: Dan's comments is correct, my bad: it's 1<<2, not 1<<3)

Comment: I would call that the fourth least significant bit.