# Set a specific bit in an int

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

I need to mask certain string values read from a database by setting a specific bit in an int value for each possible database value.  For example, if the database returns the string "value1" then the bit in position 0 will need to be set to 1, but if the database returns "value2" then the bit in position 1 will need to be set to 1 instead.

How can I ensure each bit of an int is set to 0 originally and then turn on just the specified bit?

Comment: `intValue |= 1 << position;`

Comment: Read up on [bit wise operators](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1544/Bit-wise-operations-in-C) too. Always good to know

Comment: @elgonzo, I like your solution better (since you don't need to figure out the hex number). I would upvote if it was an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to unset a specific bit in an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557105/how-to-unset-a-specific-bit-in-an-integer)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, don't push an old and very sloooow man ;-)

Comment: There's a [similar question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93744/most-common-c-sharp-bitwise-operations-on-enums) on SO already, it may provide a better insight for what you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a specific bit from byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854207/get-a-specific-bit-from-byte)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you have an int value "*intValue*" and you want to set a specific bit at position "*bitPosition*", do something like:

```
intValue = intValue | (1 << bitPosition);
```

or shorter:

```
intValue |= 1 << bitPosition;
```

If you want to reset a bit (i.e, set it to zero), you can do this:

```
intValue &= ~(1 << bitPosition);
```

(The operator `~` reverses each bit in a value, thus `~(1 << bitPosition)` will result in an *int* where every bit is *1* except the bit at the given *bitPosition*.)

Answer (score 11):

To set everything to 0, AND the value with 0x00000000:

```
int startValue = initialValue & 0x00000000;
//Or much easier :)
int startValue = 0;
```

To then set the bit, you have to determine what number has **just that bit** set and OR it. For example, to set the last bit:

```
int finalValue = startValue | 0x00000001;
```

As @Magus points out, to unset a bit you do the exact opposite:

```
int finalValue = startValue & 0xFFFFFFFE;
//Or
int finalValue = startValue & ~(0x00000001);
```

The ~ operatior is *bitwise not* which flips every bit.

Comment: Might also mention that an `&` with all `1`s and one `0` will set the specified bit to `0`, in case that's needed.

Comment: Hmm, complex way of setting it to 0, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasW. Indeed, changed the code to enhance the "just assign to 0" option. It does illustrate the later code better though (IMO).

Comment: to reset a value, you can xor it with itself

Comment: @aduch, a very interesting approach of setting it to 0. It would certainly work, but might be the most confusing of the three.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes I understand it's confusing at first. It is also widely used in assembly to reset registers.

Comment: @aduch, Good old assembly :) Sign of the apocalypse: When C# is written that includes assembly and/or assebmly-level optimizations

Comment: @BradleyDotNET As long as your algorithm is optimized first, that makes sense to me. Without an optimized algorithm, bitwise operations are kind of useless.

Comment: I just noticed (about 5 years later; go figure) that you had 0xFFFFFFF7 in your code example instead of 0xFFFFFFFE ( = ~0x00000001). Hope you don't mind that i "bug-fixed" your code example ;-)

Answer (score 4):

so, this?

```
enum ConditionEnum 
{
    Aaa = 0,
    Bbb = 1,
    Ccc = 2,
}    

static void SetBit(ref int bitFlag, ConditionEnum condition, bool bitValue)
{
    int mask = 1 << (int)condition;
    if (bitValue)
        bitFlag |= mask;
    else
        bitFlag &= ~mask;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just provide a value, bit value and position. Note that you might be able to modify this to work for other types.

```
public static void SetBit(ref int value, bool bitval, int bitpos)
    {
        if (!bitval) value&=~(1<<bitpos); else value|=1<<bitpos;
    }
```